# How to Embed a Plotly Interactive Graph in Webpage

Tags: python, django, plotly, plotly-dash

I have an interactive graph generated by Plotly in Python that I saved to an html file using `plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='/tmp/interactiveGraph.html')`

I am now trying to embed this interactive graph into some kind of webpage, using either Dash or Django. I'm leaning toward Django at the moment, given that I have an html version of the graph. **Which would be better?**

My code for the webpage is in a separate file from the code where I am creating the graph.

A lot of the tutorials I've found online just say to add a few lines to the template, but I don't know how to get those lines that they've described.

**tl;dr: I'm looking for guidance as how to integrate an html file-for a Plotly interactive graph-with a web python script using Django or Dash**

*Side Question:*

what is the difference between

```
plotly.offline.plot(fig, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
```

and what I have above?

Reference:

https://github.com/ricleal/DjangoPlotLy

https://www.pythonsetup.com/how-implement-data-visualization-django-and-plotly/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly reccomend Django, its a great framework. As for this, the best option is to generate the data via JavaScript and Plotly has a great library for this. If you must use python, then Django can be used. Assuming you are familiar with Django, inside of your view you can collect your data and build your graph ( I would reccomend a celery task for something long running like this unless they are small graphs), and you can then collect the return from creating the graph in div format. This will return a string that holds all the needed html and css for the graphs. Put this inside of you get_context_data() method in your view and place it into the dictionary. You can the use that object inside of a template. I have done this before, if you are having a hard time feel free to DM me. Hope this helps some!

In regards to your side question, I believe having False for including JS will make the graph a bit smaller assuming you have an include for the plotly JS library. They might have done this in a newer release to make the graphs faster as they were significantly slower in the browser from python that the JS rendered one.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, how can I direct message on here?

Comment: I am not quite sure to be honest, I had someone do it with me the other day let me look!

Comment: @ Theodore Howell, perhaps just communicating this way is best?

Comment: Works with me, what else are you having issues with at this point?

Comment: @ Theodore Howell...The way my code is currently set up, I have a python script that is accessing logs and aggregating data. This data is then being graphed to Plotly and saved as an html file. I want to take this data and create a webpage(in a different script) with a collection of similar html files. I'm not sure if your answer helps me with this specifically?

Comment: but it does, you need to create that graph inside a django view and then put it in the context data to present it in the template, or better yet query the data from the front end and use the plotly js library, much friendlier experince.

Comment: which is better approach. using javascript library and fetch only data from django or generate the offline plot in django with css and html and pass it into the template